# blank javascript file inclusion causing redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm including a javascript file that is blank. When loaded using `appendChild` from the `head` it redirects to the homepage with a redirect response. The location of the file is correct. When I try to access it via the browser it also goes back to the homepage.

is there an issue with loading blank javascript files onto a page?

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration for your webserver, if the file exists, there should be no reason for the redirect. And if you view a JavaScript file in the browser, it definitely shouldn't execute any code. My guess is that the file is missing, and the server redirects to the homepage in case of 404. Try a URL that is not an existing file, see if you get the same redirection.